# Google automatically signed in without asking which account

Tags: javascript

I am using Google sign in for my website. When am signed in first time it is asking for choose account. Second time, when I clicked on sign in button it is signed in automatically without asking choose account.
Here the sign out code:

```
function signOut() {
 var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
 auth2.signOut().then(function () {
  console.log('User signed out.');
 });
};
```

This code used for sign out from my website but not from google.

I just want to show choose account option to sign in every time. When the user chooses account it should sign in automatically. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you signed out first?

Comment: If you are using Passport and want to make sure you are signed out, you can use the req.logout() function that is exposed by the framework.

Comment: I got it. When I signed in with two or more google accounts in my device it is asking for choose account. Otherwise it is signing in automatically. Previously I did not sign in with two or more accounts in my device. Thanks for your comments